# Transposing lines containing Text to columns

Tags: sql

I have a table just like this one:

```
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
| ID | Period  | Total Units |   Source   | 
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
|  1 | Past    |         400 | Competitor | 
|  1 | Present |         250 | PAWS       |  
|  2 | Past    |           3 | BP         | 
|  2 | Present |          15 | BP         |  
+----+---------+-------------+------------+
```

And I'm trying to transpose the lines into columns, so that for each ID, I have one unique line that compares past and present numbers and attributes. Like following :

```
+----+------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
| ID | Total Units Past | Total Units Present | Source Past | Source Present |
+----+------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
|  1 |              400 |                 250 | Competitor  | PAWS           
|
|  2 |                3 |                  15 | BP          | BP             |
+----+------------------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Transposing the total units is not a problem, as I use a SUM(CASE WHEN Period = Past THEN Total_Units ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Units.

However I don't know how to proceed with text columns. I've seen some pivot and unpivot clause used but they all use an aggregate function at some point.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: For now I've used two separate subqueries, one for past and one for present, which I have then joined, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select id,
       sum(case when period = 'past' then units else 0 end) as unitspast,
       sum(case when period = 'present' then units else 0 end) as unitpresent,
       max(case when period = 'past' then source end) as sourcepast,
       max(case when period = 'present' then source end) as sourcepresent
from table t
group by id;
```

Comment: So the MAX aggregate will consider text also, thanks for the learnings! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have two rows per ID, you could also join:

```
Select a.ID, a.units as UnitsPast, a.source as SourcePast
     , b.units as UnitsPresent, b.source as SourcePresent
from MyTable a
left join MyTable b
on a.ID = b.ID
and b.period = 'Present'
where a.period = 'Past'
```

Comment: i guess `group by` within same table and `conditional aggregation` looks a better option as correctly implemented by @Yogesh Sharma's answer

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I usually prefer to avoid aggregations when they're not necessary, as they can hide underlying data quality issues (for example, two "past" rows for the same ID), but to each her own.

Comment: but what if in case theres huge amount of data and if the data is fetched already via join then in those cases self join will cause performance issues.

Comment: Nothing in the question indicates that that is the case.  Why are you so invested in someone else's answer?  Let the person who asked choose whichever they prefer.

Comment: There is in fact a pretty big amount of data, thank you for pointing that out. But this technique is interesting also